# python sqlalchemy how to change column type between table define and execute Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, TEXT, create_engine, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase


class SqlalchemyBase(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class ListPage(SqlalchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = "list_page"
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    page_condition = Column(TEXT,nullable=False)

# I want change the page_condition column type from TEXT to String(200)
ListPage.page_condition = Column(String(200),nullable=False)

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}")
SqlalchemyBase.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

i want change column type after table define,
for example:change the page_condition column type from TEXT to String(200) ,
but i get error,
what's the right way.
thanks

background:
This is a question I have while working on data processing. I hope to extract a generic data model, but as you know, data comes in various forms, with subtle differences. Creating a new model every time a new type appears can become overly complex. Don't you think that initially defining fixed types can be limiting? So, I hope that even though I define a model initially, I can have complete control over it, including controlling the table name, field types, and the number of fields. So far, I have figured out how to dynamically control table names and dynamically add fields. However, I haven't found a method for changing field types after defining the model. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not just set the desired type in the class definition?

Comment: Not that this is necessarily impossible, but it sounds like you might have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Even if you don't, more context might help to iden=tify the best solution.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thank you for your response,i’ve added background description.
My goal is to have complete control over the table model even after it's been defined, rather than having it rigidly defined from the start. My business scenario doesn't involve web development; I'm working with data, which is subject to change. I don't want to redefine a model every time there's a minor data variation. I want to make quick adjustments to these changes through code, rather than defining numerous data models.